# How to merge in master?

Tags: git, github, merge

I created a branch "feature200" based on another subbranch "score" of master. Now I am 103 commits behind master.

Do I merge master into "feature200" or merge "feature200" into master? ALSO feature200 needs to be approved via pull request on github so keep that in mind when answering.

Branches
master > score > feature200

feature200 is 103 commits behind master and I need to get master code into feature200 and then submit a pull request for feature200.

Hope I said this right.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to be followed:

1. git checkout Master
2. git pull
3. git checkout feature200
4. git rebase Master
5. git checkout Master
6. git merge feature

With this you have all the changes (103 commits of feature200) on Master as well as the latest Master changes(latest pulled changes)